# What does this command do? "exec bash -l"

Tags: linux, shell, unix, exec

What does this command do?

```
exec bash -l
```

I found this command as part of a reminder text file were I wrote some instructions regarding how to create a ssh key and clone a git repo, but I wrote it a long time ago and I can't remember what it does.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`exec` executes a specified command, replacing the current process rather than starting a new subprocess.

If you type

```
bash -l
```

at a shell prompt, it will invoke a new shell process (the `-l` makes it a login shell). If you exit that shell process, you'll be back to your original shell process.

Typing

```
exec bash -l
```

means that the new shell process *replaces* your current shell process. It's probably slightly less resource intensive.

The reason for doing it is probably so that the new shell sets up its environment (by reading your `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, etc.).

See the bash documentation for more information:

- [Bash Startup Files](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) for how a login shell differs from a non-login shell
- [Bourne Shell Builtins](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html) for documentation on the `exec` command.

(You should be able to read the manual on your own system by typing `info bash`.)

Answer (score 1):

This will replace your current shell with a new bash shell run as a login shell.

Comment: It doesn't just execute it; `bash -l` without the `exec` does that. See my answer.