# Command results work locally but not over ssh

Tags: bash, shell

I run this command on my remote machine and it gives the desired results:

```
local# /usr/local/sbin/i2c_eeprom show-serial
serial = 5070045
```

When I run it from a remote server it doesn't work:

```
server# sshpass -f pass.out ssh 192.168.1.1 -n -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" "i2c_eeprom show-serial"
serial = TBD Serial
```

Why isn't the result being display correctly?  I've tried creating a script file first and redirecting the output to a remote file, then reading the file but I don't get the same results.  I always get TBD Serial.  Any suggestions on how to run this command remotely and behave as it does locally?

Comment: Places you can start is to compare whether `/usr/local/sbin/i2c_eeprom` is the same version that's run in both cases, or whether the program's behavior varies based on whether it's writing to a TTY, or whether there are SELinux or other security-context restrictions in play based on which process it was started from, or whether the user accounts vary.

Comment: Another place to start is to generate an `strace` log of the actual syscalls from both invocation modes, and to compare those two logs. If you see an error happen in one case that doesn't happen in another, that gives you a place to dig.

Comment: ...the number of possible causes for a program's behavior to change between invocation modes is almost endless, though. Maybe it's depending on an environment variable set it a user's dotfiles for interactive sessions only. The room for speculation is so wide as to make that speculation of very little use.

Comment: Why are you running with full path locally but not remotely? Are both running as root?

Comment: I'm using the full path both places.

Comment: It is not clear if you are running the command twice on the same machine but once on console and once over ssh; or running the command once on each of two different machines.

Comment: I changed the examples.  The first example I'm running from the command line on the client (local).  The second example I'm using ssh from another server (server) to run the same command.

Comment: This is interesting, I put the command in a cron job and had it write to a file, I don't get the desired results either.  It appears this is not an SSH thing as I initially though.

Comment: That's in line with some of my early guesses: A cron job doesn't have a TTY either, and is also likely to be treated more like a daemon (that should be protected against shell injection and privilege escalation) and less like an administrator (who should be allowed to do absolutely anything unrestricted) by common SELinux policies.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating a bash script on the server as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
/usr/local/sbin/i2c_eeprom show-serial
```

I copy this to the client and execute it via ssh.  The key is the "-l" in the shebang line.  I found this solution here.  [What does this command do? "exec bash -l"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26747455/what-does-this-command-do-exec-bash-l)

Comment: You should figure out *why* having a login shell makes a difference, and incorporate that change into your script more narrowly. Running your user's dotfiles from a noninteractive interpreter is not good practice -- dotfiles change as users' preferences do; people shouldn't need to worry that a change they make to their account configuration will break random scripts.